# Solve the ODE and determine a solution limited by $t \to \frac{\pi}{2} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

Find a general solution of the following equation:

$x' \sin(2t)=2(x+\cos(t))$.

Determine a solution limited by $t \to \frac{\pi}{2} $.

$x' = \frac{2(x+\cos(t))}{\sin(2t)} \Rightarrow x' - \frac{2x}{\sin(2t)} = \frac{\cos(t)}{\sin(2t)} $

First we can solve a homogeneous equation, and then after variation of parameters we can solve inhomogeneous equation. That's right, but there will be very difficult integers to compute, and even if I will be able to solve it (after some time), I don't know what to do with "Determine a solution limited by $t \to \frac{\pi}{2} $".

I think that there may be some different, easier way to solve our equation, but yet, I don't recognize any. Can we transform this to exact differential equation?

Btw  wolfram alpha says that the solution is $x(t)=C_1 tan(t)-sec(t)$, don't know if it will help but... .

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to your second question only.

Assume that we know that 
$$
\frac{C \sin{t} - 1}{\cos{t}}
$$
is a general solution of the ODE.  Of course, for no value of $C$ the above function is defined at $t = \pi/2$.  But we want to find $C$ such that the function has a (finite) limit as $t \to \pi/2$.

The denominator tends to zero as $t \to \pi/2$, so a necessary condition is that $C \sin{t} - 1 \to 0$ as $t \to \pi/2$.  The only possibility left is $C = 1$.

Notice that this is only a *necessary* condition.  We have to check that
$$
\frac{\sin{t} - 1}{\cos{t}}
$$
tends to a finite limit as $t \to \pi/2$.  Indeed, this limit is $0$.